# Proving this series convergence: limit with factorial

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to prove this series convergence

$ \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} {\frac{1}3}^\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$

I'm still trying to figure out the best process but what I tried to do was to say that my series is always equal or more than the series

$ \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} {\frac{1}3}^\frac{1}{n!}$

Now to prove the divergence (I hope, if it's convergent than my process won't work) I'm trying to calculate the limit of $\frac{1}{3}^\frac{1}{n!}$. But I don't know how to calculate this limit (because of the factorial)... Should I proceed the same way I would if I had $\frac{1}{3}^\frac{1}{n}$? Or is it different with the factorial?

Comment: It's cannot be convergent as the general term doesn't converge to $0$ (in fact, it converges to $1$).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the simple test of divergence to show that this series diverges:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{3}^{\frac{1}{(n-1)!}} = \frac{1}{3}^0 = 1$$

Since this limit doesn't equal $0$, we can therefore conclude that this series diverges by the Test for Divergence.